# How to Use the values of #Temp Tables inside where clause of OPENQUERY SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, db2, teradata, temp-tables, openquery

So I have to take data from Teradata and DB2 and load it into the SQL table. I created a Temp table and inserted the required value from Teradata. I want to use the values stored in the Temp table in the query which connects the DB2 using OPENQUERY.

SO Inside the OPENQUERY, I am using the Temp table. But unfortunately, it's throwing errors.

Can you please help me how to resolve this or any alternative?

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
select * into #Temp from OPENQUERY(TD2P,'select age,pin from schema.teratable')

insert into dbo.tbl1
select * from OPENQUERY(DB2P, 'select name, age, number from schema.tablename where AGE in (select age in #temp where pin > 50 )')
```

**ERROR:**

OLEDB provider 'db2xx' for linked server "DB2P" returned message "[DB2] SQL0204N "#Temp" is an undefined name SQLSTATE=42704

Cannot get column information from OLEDB provider 'db2xx' for linked server 'DB2P'.

Comment: Short answer - you can't do this. The query you pass to your linked server is executed within that db2 connection and your temp table is not visible to that engine. Using a proper ETL tool is a far better choice. Othewise, you will need to retrieve the contents of "schema.tablename" (nice name btw) and then join to your temp table - which might be terribly inefficient.

Comment: And since you don't apparently need any rows where pin <= 50 (or null), just DON'T bring them over into your temp table.

Comment: Pull everything onto a single system and process it there.

Comment: You'll need to join the result of `openquery` against the Db2 resources with your temp table on the SQL Server side.

Comment: How about if the user inserts into global temp table via open query, and then again using open query join the table with global temp table?